Use of 果たす vs 果たし, masu-stem verbs?
Example:
よいな。16歳となったおぬしたちは神の岩で成人の儀式を果たし一人前の大人にならなくてはいかん。
In this line of dialogue, I don't understand the grammar here in regards to 果たし and its connection to 一人前の大人 after it. Am I right in understanding that 果たし is the masu stem of 果たします here, and it's not something else going on? In that case, why is it 果たし and not the full 果たします, or the simple verb form of 果たす; is it about different grammar in how it then links to 一人前の大人?
I tried to look this up but I couldn't find any relevant use cases, so I'm not sure what this case of grammar would be called. I have a sense that 果たす would be wrong here, but I can't find an explanation of why, or what 果たし is that makes it work here.

Does this answer your question? Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause? / Masu stem to connect sentences

@naruto It does, thank you. I can't see how to mark your comment as the answer, though.
